# How to move files based on filename using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and am stuck at something.

How to move files based on filename using PowerShell?

Move   `0001_ddmmyy_username[active1]_L_kkkkk.pdf` to C:\Users\abc\London
Move   `0001_ddmmyy_jacky[active1]_R_kkkkk.pdf` to C:\Users\abc\Russia
Move   `0001_ddmmyy_jim[active1]_P_kkkkk.pdf` to C:\Users\abc\Poland

I used the following code to move files to a folder called London. It fails if the file name has any square bracket with text [kkkk].

```
gci 'C:\Users\abc' -Recurse -Include "*_L*" | %{ Move-Item $_.FullName 'C:\Users\abc\London'}
```

How can I automate this?

Comment: with some cmdlets, you will get odd results when you use `-Path` and any part of the full file name contains `[]`. it also happens with some other chars, but those are the only ones i recall. the fix is to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter instead of the `-Path` parameter. **_you are using the `-Path` parameter since you failed to specify anything - and the cmdlets default to `-Path`._** take a look at the output of `Get-Help Move-Item -Parameter *path*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.

How to move files based on file basename using PowerShell `gci`, `foreach`, `if`, `-like`, `move-item` and `-literalpath`

Move   `0001_ddmmyy_username[active1]_L_kkkkk.pdf` to `C:\Users\abc\London`
Move   `0001_ddmmyy_jacky[active1]_R_kkkkk.pdf` to `C:\Users\abc\Russia`
Move   `0001_ddmmyy_jim[active1]_P_kkkkk.pdf` to `C:\Users\abc\Poland`

Change `$env:userprofile\desktop`. Remove `-whatif` when you are satisfied it works.

```
$items = gci -recurse -file *_L_*, *_R_*, *_P_*
foreach($item in $items) {
  # Change $env:userprofile\desktop
  if($item -like "*_L_*") {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item "$env:userprofile\desktop\London" -whatif
  } elseif($item -like "*_R_*") {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item "$env:userprofile\desktop\Russia" -whatif
  } elseif ($item -like '*_P_*') {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item "$env:userprofile\desktop\Poland" -whatif 
  }
}
```

Comments:

With some cmdlets you will get odd results when you use `-Path` and any part of the full file name contains []. The fix is to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter. See `Get-Help Move-Item -Parameter *path*` – Lee_Dailey

How to move files based on file basename using PowerShell gci, foreach, if, -like, move-item and -literalpath

Comment: Hello My friend, 
It works perfectly, a minor addition is to have 
1. Create folder if it does not exist and then move it based on the current directory
2. Check if files with same name exists and if yes do not move or replace it
Really appreciate your help

Comment: Noted and sorry about that as I was new to the forum.

Comment: @somebadhat I have created a new thread. Could you please help?

Comment: @cur comment to me from your new post.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are multiple ways:

Get-Location

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location?view=powershell-7

```bsh
gci (Get-Location).Path
```

or simply `.\`

```bsh
gci .\
```

additionaly, gci will default to current path if none is specified. So the following will get the current folder:

```bsh
gci
```

2. Use `-LiteralPath` in the `Move-Item` cmdlet.

```bsh
Move-Item -LiteralPath $sourcePath $destinationPath
```

3. I'd do something similar to below:

```bsh
# Note I'm using -File so it only returns files
$items = gci .\ -Recurse -File -Include *_L*, *_R*, *_P*

foreach($item in $items) {
  # Could utilize something cleaner/better but this will do
  if($item.Name -like "*_L*") {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item 'C:\Users\abc\London'
  } elseif($item.Name -like "*_R*") {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item 'C:\Users\abc\Russia'
  } elseif ($item.Name -like "*_P*") {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item 'C:\Users\abc\Poland'
  } else {
    # Unexpected output
    Write-Host "The path did not match what was expected"
    Write-Host $item.Name
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello My Friend,
This code gives me the exact same output as my code for _L. When the file name has some text with [xxxxxx] before the _L or _R or _P , then it will not move it.

Can you also advice on creating the folder London and moving all _L into it.

Comment: Hey, as per the response from @somebadhat, using -LiteralPath will fix the issue with the brackets.

Comment: His solution works perfectly fine, just looking at a minor improvement too. 1. Check and create the folders within the .\ and also to skip or overwrite if files exist.